# Visual Studio 2015 "cannot instantiate abstract class" compile failures building openFrameworks 0.9.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, openframeworks

I am trying to build openFrameworks 0.9.0 using Visual Studio 2015 and am getting  "cannot instantiate abstract class" compile failures. However, I feel this is more likely a VS2015 syntax issue versus an openFrameworks issue. This code built using Visual Studio 2012 and openFrameworks 0.8.4. Does anyone know how the implementing class's syntax should look to satisfy VS2015 should look?

The errors from VS2015 compile are:

```
ofx*.cpp(46): error C2259: 'ofx*': cannot instantiate abstract class 1> ......\addons\ofx*I\libs\src\ofx*.cpp(46): note: due to following members: 1> ......\addons\ofx*I\libs\src\ofx*.cpp(46): note: 'void ofBaseDraws::draw(float,float,float,float) const': is abstract 1> ...of_v0.9.0_vs_release\libs\openFrameworks\types\ofBaseTypes.h(75): note: see declaration of 'ofBaseDraws::draw'

1> ......\addons\ofx*I\libs\src\ofx*.cpp(46): note: 'void ofBaseDraws::draw(float,float) const': is abstract 1> ...of_v0.9.0_vs_release\libs\openFrameworks\types\ofBaseTypes.h(67): note: see declaration of 'ofBaseDraws::draw'

1> ......\addons\ofx*I\libs\src\ofx*.cpp(46): note: 'float ofBaseDraws::getHeight(void) const': is abstract 1> ...of_v0.9.0_vs_release\libs\openFrameworks\types\ofBaseTypes.h(104): note: see declaration of 'ofBaseDraws::getHeight'

1> ......\addons\ofx*I\libs\src\ofx*.cpp(46): note: 'float ofBaseDraws::getWidth(void) const': is abstract 1> ...of_v0.9.0_vs_release\libs\openFrameworks\types\ofBaseTypes.h(108): note: see declaration of 'ofBaseDraws::getWidth'
```

The code from the inherited class:
   of_v0.9.0_vs_release\libs\openFrameworks\types\ofBaseTypes.h

has the abstract object: ofBaseDraws...which has the following declarations:

```
/// \brief Draw at a position at the native size.
///
/// Native size is determined by getWidth() and getHeight().
///
/// \param x Draw position on the x axis.
/// \param y Draw position on the y axis.
virtual void draw(float x, float y) const=0;

/// \brief Draw at a position with the specified size.
///
/// \param x Draw position on the x axis.
/// \param y Draw position on the y axis.
/// \param w Draw width.
/// \param h Draw height.
virtual void draw(float x, float y, float w, float h) const=0;
```

is as follows:

```
/// \brief Draw at a position at the native size.
///
/// Native size is determined by getWidth() and getHeight().
///
/// \param x Draw position on the x axis.
/// \param y Draw position on the y axis.
virtual void draw(float x, float y) const=0;

/// \brief Draw at a position with the specified size.
///
/// \param x Draw position on the x axis.
/// \param y Draw position on the y axis.
/// \param w Draw width.
/// \param h Draw height.
virtual void draw(float x, float y, float w, float h) const=0;
...............................................

/// \brief Get the height.
/// \returns the height.
virtual float getHeight() const = 0;

/// \brief Get the width.
/// \returns the width.
virtual float getWidth() const = 0;
```

---

The openFrameworks 0.8.4 code that built with VS2012 was slightly different:

```
virtual void draw(float x, float y)=0;
virtual void draw(float x, float y, float w, float h)=0;
...............................................
virtual float getHeight()=0;
virtual float getWidth()=0;
```

Comment: Found convention in: of_v0.9.0_vs_release\libs\openFrameworks\gl\ofTexture.h:

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but must admit finding the answer myself (embarrassed):

Found convention in: of_v0.9.0_vs_release\libs\openFrameworks\gl\ofTexture.h:

```
using ofBaseDraws::draw;

void draw(float x, float y) const;
void draw(float x, float y, float w, float h) const;
float getHeight() const;
float getWidth() const;

//*** and in ofTexture.cpp:

void draw(float x, float y) {
.....
}
void draw(float x, float y, float w, float h) {
....
}
float getHeight() {
return height;
}
float getWidth() {
return width;
}
```